# Script that choose registry file based on whether the computer has nvidia or not

Tags: powershell, cmd

Hi my scripting friends!

My issue: I have received two Registry files, both files are in the fileset i have made. I have to create a script that says that if the Computer has "Nvidia" graphic card then it should run **"Registry C7.2.13 m-graf.reg"**. And if it does not have "Nvidia" then it must run **"Registry C7.2.13 u-graf.reg"**.

Is this something anyone here can help me with, i I have little experience with scripting?

Tnx :D

Answer (score 2):

You can find what videocard you have using `Get-CimInstance` and then use reg.exe to import the needed script:

```
if ((Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_VideoController).Description -like '*nvidia*') {
    reg.exe import "X:\FullPathTo\Registry C7.2.13 m-graf.reg"
}
else {
    reg.exe import "X:\FullPathToRegistry C7.2.13 u-graf.reg"
}
```

<sup>See [Get-CimInstance vs. Get-WmiObject](https://www.pdq.com/blog/powershell-guide-get-ciminstance-and-get-wmiobject/)</sup>